# Register allocation optimization in a C compiler written in ocaml

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, register-allocation

What is the fastest graph implementation for removing and adding vertices?

It seems like this part of my C compiler is the slowest, and can take up to 9/10 ms per vertex removed (which is a really long time when there are something like 60,000 vertices in the graph).

If not is there some way to do maximum cardinality search (for simplicial elimination ordering construction) without removing vertices?

Comment: With a straightforward balanced tree (Map) you can insert and delete vertices in O(log n) time it seems to me. What are you doing now?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the implementation is for ocamlgraph, but according to the documentation, it takes O(V * d) where d is the max degree in the graph. I'm gonna try out your idea and just place the vertices into a tree as well since space is really not an issue.

I'm currently using ocamlgraph for the graph data structure.

Comment: Using Hashtbl you could do it in O(1).

Comment: Please change the title and tags of your question. While your use case might be register-allocation in a C compiler the problem you describe in the body mentions none of that and seems to be purely a problem of how you (ocamlgraph) represents graphs.